# Fill in missing data that is same across columns

Tags: r

I need to fill in some missing data from a merge that is the same in all columns.  After the merge, all the values are `NA`, but i would like a quick way to fill them in since their values are the same.

Example:

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(-25932, -25931, -25930, -25929, 
-25928), class = "Date"), year = c(1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899
), month = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), day = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), test1 = c(NA, 
NA, "VAR1", NA, NA), test2 = c(NA, NA, "VAR2", NA, NA), test3 = c(NA, 
NA, "VAR3", NA, NA)), .Names = c("date", "year", "month", "day", 
"test1", "test2", "test3"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

# Tedious way, but works
df$test1 <- "VAR1"

# Desired output
    date     year month day test1 test2 test3
1 1899-01-01 1899     1   1  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3
2 1899-01-02 1899     1   2  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3
3 1899-01-03 1899     1   3  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3
4 1899-01-04 1899     1   4  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3
5 1899-01-05 1899     1   5  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3
```

Comment: `library(zoo); na.locf(na.locf(df), fromLast = TRUE)`?

Comment: Or: `df[grep("test", names(df))] <- lapply(df[grep("test", names(df))], function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like the following:

```
df
#         date year month day test1 test2 test3
# 1 1899-01-01 1899     1   1  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
# 2 1899-01-02 1899     1   2  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
# 3 1899-01-03 1899     1   3  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3
# 4 1899-01-04 1899     1   4  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
# 5 1899-01-05 1899     1   5  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>

df[grep("test", names(df))] <- lapply(df[grep("test", names(df))], 
                                      function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1])
df
#         date year month day test1 test2 test3
# 1 1899-01-01 1899     1   1  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3
# 2 1899-01-02 1899     1   2  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3
# 3 1899-01-03 1899     1   3  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3
# 4 1899-01-04 1899     1   4  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3
# 5 1899-01-05 1899     1   5  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if the column names are different and not similar like in this example?

Comment: Yup that worked, and much fast than the `zoo` function.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `data.table`. Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`).  Based on the index of 'test' columns ('nm1'), we loop with `for` and `set` the `NA` elements by the non-NA elements in each column.

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- grep('^test', names(df))
setDT(df)
for(j in nm1){
  set(df, i=which(is.na(df[[j]])), j=j, value= na.omit(df[[j]]))
 }
df
#          date year month day test1 test2 test3
#1: 1899-01-01 1899     1   1  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3
#2: 1899-01-02 1899     1   2  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3
#3: 1899-01-03 1899     1   3  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3
#4: 1899-01-04 1899     1   4  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3
#5: 1899-01-05 1899     1   5  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3
```